# How to create new column by calculating on specific time range in python?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, datetime

I have a dataframe like this,

```
ID   col1            col2   
A    2018/07/01       3     
A    2018/08/01       5   
A    2018/10/01       10      
B    2018/07/01       4        
B    2018/10/01       7         
B    2019/01/01       9       
B    2019/04/01       12       
C    2018/07/01       6        
C    2018/09/01       5  
C    2018/10/01       7
```

I tried to create a new column `col3`, which calculated by `col2` for each ID minus 3 months after itself.

The results will be like,

```
 ID   col1            col2       col3
    A    2018/07/01       3          -7
    A    2018/08/01       5          NaN
    A    2018/10/01       10         NaN
    B    2018/07/01       4          -3
    B    2018/10/01       7          -2
    B    2019/01/01       9          -3
    B    2019/04/01       12         NaN
    C    2018/07/01       6          -1
    C    2018/09/01       5          NaN
    C    2018/10/01       7          NaN
```

If there is no months find for each ID after 3 months, then return a NaN.

Answer (score 0):

Supposedly it is easy with `shift(freq='-3M')` but somehow that doesn't work with month begins. So we can do:

```
# month end date
df['col1e'] = df.col1 + pd.DateOffset(months=3) - pd.DateOffset(days=1)

# shift by group
new_df = df.set_index('col1e').col2.shift(freq='-3M').reset_index(name='col3')

# copy the ID values
new_df['ID'] = df['ID'].values

# merge
df = df.merge(new_df, on=['col1e','ID'],how='left')

#final result
df['col3'] = df['col2'] - df['col3']
```

Output:

```
  ID       col1  col2      col1e  col3
0  A 2018-07-01     3 2018-09-30  -7.0
1  A 2018-08-01     5 2018-10-31   NaN
2  A 2018-10-01    10 2018-12-31   NaN
3  B 2018-07-01     4 2018-09-30  -3.0
4  B 2018-10-01     7 2018-12-31  -2.0
5  B 2019-01-01     9 2019-03-31  -3.0
6  B 2019-04-01    12 2019-06-30   NaN
7  C 2018-07-01     6 2018-09-30  -1.0
8  C 2018-09-01     5 2018-11-30   NaN
9  C 2018-10-01     7 2018-12-31   NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

Group by ID and set the date column as your Index and Resample. Then shift by -3.

In:

```
def func(df):
    df = df.set_index(df.col1).resample('MS').asfreq()
    df['col3'] = df.col2 - df.col2.shift(-3)

    # Clean Up DataFrame        
    df = df.reset_index(0, drop=True).reset_index(drop=True).dropna(how='all')

    return df

df = pd.read_clipboard()
df.col1 = pd.to_datetime(df.col1)
group = df.groupby('ID', as_index=False)

df = group.apply(func).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Out:

```
|    | ID | col1       | col2 | col3 |
|----|----|------------|------|------|
| 0  | A  | 2018-07-01 | 3.0  | -7.0 |
| 1  | A  | 2018-08-01 | 5.0  | NaN  |
| 2  | A  | 2018-10-01 | 10.0 | NaN  |
| 3  | B  | 2018-07-01 | 4.0  | -3.0 |
| 4  | B  | 2018-10-01 | 7.0  | -2.0 |
| 5  | B  | 2019-01-01 | 9.0  | -3.0 |
| 6  | B  | 2019-04-01 | 12.0 | NaN  |
| 7  | C  | 2018-07-01 | 6.0  | -1.0 |
| 8  | C  | 2018-09-01 | 5.0  | NaN  |
| 9  | C  | 2018-10-01 | 7.0  | NaN  |
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use "reindex" in the data frame groups (no resample and no shift):

```
def get_col2(grp):
    return grp.set_index("col1").reindex(grp["date2"],axis="index")["col2"]      

df["col3"]= df.assign(date2=df["col1"]+pd.offsets.MonthBegin(3)).groupby("ID").apply(get_col2).values

df["col3"]= df["col2"]-df["col3"]
```

Output:

```
ID       col1  col2  col3
0  A 2018-07-01     3  -7.0
1  A 2018-08-01     5   NaN
2  A 2018-10-01    10   NaN
3  B 2018-07-01     4  -3.0
4  B 2018-10-01     7  -2.0
5  B 2019-01-01     9  -3.0
6  B 2019-04-01    12   NaN
7  C 2018-07-01     6  -1.0
8  C 2018-09-01     5   NaN
9  C 2018-10-01     7   NaN
```